# Want to get array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below.

Here, I am getting array `key` like `[_aDeviceTokens:protected] => Array`.

```
$array= ApnsPHP_Message Object
    (
        [_bAutoAdjustLongPayload:protected] => 1
        [_aDeviceTokens:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => BD74940085E1579333E93B7D172CF82F5A3E0B17617D904107CD77573C42CEC9
            )

        [_sText:protected] => test
        [_nBadge:protected] => 1
        [_sSound:protected] => default
        [_sCategory:protected] => 
        [_bContentAvailable:protected] => 
        [_aCustomProperties:protected] => Array
            (
                [channel_id] => 1xxxx8
                [detail_id] => 1
            )

        [_nExpiryValue:protected] => 1500
        [_mCustomIdentifier:protected] => 
         )
```

As an array have object value so I am trying to get value of this key like,

```
$array->_aDeviceTokens:protected[0]
```

But this gives me an error.

So how can I achieve the value of these array keys?

Comment: `$array[0]['_aDeviceTokens'][0]`

Comment: It is not an array, it is an object.

Comment: > Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.

Comment: Yes for this I am getting error `PHP Fatal error: Cannot access protected property ApnsPHP_Message::$_aDeviceTokens`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to access protected properties of an object that you are treating like an array.

Looking at the code here: https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP/blob/master/ApnsPHP/Message.php

There are publically accessible 'getters' for those attributes.

Extract of class ApnsPHP_Message:

```
public function getCustomIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->_mCustomIdentifier;
    }
```

So instead of trying to access those properties as you have been, use the corresponding getter.

```
$custom_identifier = $message->getCustomIdentifier();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert object to array.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($array),true);
```

Now, you get value from **$array** like this

```
$array['_aDeviceTokens:protected'][0]
```

Comment: Please don't suggest this approach.